# Using Margin: auto; is not centering div

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, margin

`Margin: auto;` isn't centering this `<div class="users">`.

```css
    .users {
        margin: auto;
    }
    
    .admin {
        margin: 5px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: grey;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px grey;
        background: white;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff , #F1F1F1);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff , #F1F1F1);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff , #F1F1F1);
        background: linear-gradient(#fff , #F1F1F1);
    }
    
    .admin img {
        display: block;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: grey;
        max-width: 100%;
        margin: auto;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px grey;
    }
    
    .info {
        position: relative;
        background-color: #E0E0E0;
    }
    
    .info h1 {
        padding-top: 10px;
    }
    
    .info h3 {
        margin-top: 0px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    
    .info h1, h3 {
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
```

```html
        <div class="users">
            <div class="aboutrow">
             <div class="col-md-3 sub admin">
                                <img class=".image-responsive" src="images/pfpics/nord.jpg"></img>
              <div class="info">
                                    <h1>User</h2>
                                    <h3>Info</h3>
                                </div>
             </div>
                            
                            <div class="col-md-3 sub admin">
                                <img class=".image-responsive" src="images/pfpics/nord.jpg"></img>
              <div class="info">
                                    <h1>User</h2>
                                    <h3>Info</h3>
                                </div>
             </div>
                            
                            <div class="col-md-3 sub admin">
                                <img class=".image-responsive" src="images/pfpics/nord.jpg"></img>
              <div class="info">
                                    <h1>User</h2>
                                    <h3>Info</h3>
                                </div>
             </div>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="aboutrow">
                            <div class="col-md-3 sub admin">
                                <img class=".image-responsive" src="images/pfpics/nord.jpg"></img>
              <div class="info">
                                    <h1>User</h2>
                                    <h3>Info</h3>
                                </div>
             </div>
                        </div>
            </div>
```

Im using bootstrap to make this site, I don't know if that is messing with it or not.
I tried adding a margin percentage to the left, but that doesn't play very nicely with mobile screens.

Help will be very much appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: centering a `div` is not margin auto your `div` should have a width and then do `margin:0 auto;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the way I fixed it is by changing the HTML and CSS

From `<div class="col-md-3 sub admin">` to `<div class="col-sm-3 admin">` I'm not totally sure if that contributed, but ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Then I changed the CSS to

```
.users {
    width: -webkit-fit-content;
    width: -moz-fit-content;
    width: fit-content;
    margin: auto;

}

.admin {
    max-width: 410px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px; 
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: grey;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px grey;
    background: white;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff , #F1F1F1);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff , #F1F1F1);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff , #F1F1F1);
    background: linear-gradient(#fff , #F1F1F1);
}
```

The only problems are that it looks a bit funky on tablet sized screens, and that it's not *totally* centralised.  However, it works for now.

Answer (score 3):

For centering, we should have a `width` and then use `margin:0 auto;`

Working Sample : https://jsfiddle.net/3xhn73ct/1/

```
.users {
  width:50%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that shrinks the .admin div.

Answer (score 0):

A `div` is a `block` element by default, and thus has a default width of 100%. Even if you're setting the margin to `auto`, the element will not be centered because it's already taking all the space available.

You can either explicitely give your element a width, or set its display to `inline-block`, so that it takes only the space it needs, and set the parent's text-align to `center`.

Comment: Add a text align to a div?

Comment: If the child div (.users) is set to inline-block, then setting text-align to center on the *parent* will center the .users div.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set a width on .users and that will center the whole div.

```
.users{
  width:500px; /* for example */
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

If you are trying to just center the contents of .users you will need to do something like this

```
.users > div {
   width:500px; /* for example */
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Also since you are using bootstrap you should add a .container class to your wrapping div. That will give you your page margins.

Comment: I don't think using px would work well on mobile.  And I'm not sure what you mean by the last part

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "position: relative" to that:

```
.users {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

And that only works for horizontal centering.

For vertical centering you need to add

```
.users {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

And for this to work the parent element of `.users` needs to have a defined height.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure,if you want something like this

```css
.users {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
}
.admin {
  margin: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: grey;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px grey;
  background: white;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #F1F1F1);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #F1F1F1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #F1F1F1);
  background: linear-gradient(#fff, #F1F1F1);
}
.admin img {
  display: block;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: grey;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px grey;
}
.info {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
}
.info h1 {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="users">
  <div class="aboutrow">
    <div class="col-md-3 sub admin">
      <img class=".image-responsive" src="images/pfpics/nord.jpg"></img>
      <div class="info">
        <h1>User</h2>
                                    <h3>Info</h3>
                                </div>
             </div>
                            
                            <div class="col-md-3 sub admin">
                                <img class=".image-responsive" src="images/pfpics/nord.jpg"></img>
              <div class="info">
                                    <h1>User</h2>
                                    <h3>Info</h3>
                                </div>
             </div>
                            
                            <div class="col-md-3 sub admin">
                                <img class=".image-responsive" src="images/pfpics/nord.jpg"></img>
              <div class="info">
                                    <h1>User</h2>
                                    <h3>Info</h3>
                                </div>
             </div>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="aboutrow">
                            <div class="col-md-3 sub admin">
                                <img class=".image-responsive" src="images/pfpics/nord.jpg"></img>
              <div class="info">
                                    <h1>User</h2>
                                    <h3>Info</h3>
                                </div>
             </div>
                        </div>
            </div>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Add `width` attribute for the `.users` CSS selector, for centering the block.

Sample 1 : [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3xhn73ct/1/)

```
.users
{
    width:50%;
    margin:auto;
}
```

---OR--

One of many other ways to do it, is by giving `body` attributes of a `table` of some percentage width and the block within body i.e `div.users` as a `table cell`.

Sample 2 : [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zs0cm44r/8/)

```
.users {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

body {
    width:50%;
    display:table;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Both of these, seem to work fine with mobile screens as well (need to zoom a bit).

Comment: The first one makes the .admin div quite small.  So I added a `width: 24%" to it, and that doesn't work on mobile.  Second option doesn't work at all.  The first option just needs some tweaking, and it will work

Comment: @Qwerty-Space : I check the sample (jsFiddle).. Isn't that what you wanted to centre the `.users` block..

Comment: Yes, but it didn't work in practice.  I've fixed it though.

Comment: @Qwerty-Space : `24% width` is fine for Big screens but it looks very small for mobile screens... Although we can zoom*, I would suggest you to make it responsive...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `margin: auto;` to center a div, you will need to explicitly give a "width" to the div, and most importantly, if you want to see it work, you MUST have the width lesser than the width of your screen.

Answer (score 0):

Use following, it will work :

.users

{
text-align:center;

}